# Public IP Web Page "Connection Timed Out" When Connected To

Tags: apache, networking, wampserver

Recently, I made a website server on my server PC running Windows 7. I used WampServer, and I configured it as follows:

1. Download and install WampServer.
2. Check http://localhost (worked).
3. Program out the HTML files necessary.
4. Put it inside of the 'www' directory (the default directory of WampServer for HTML files)
5. Go to http://localhost to see if it worked (yes, it did). Then right click WAMP notification and "Put online".
6. Go to my main PC and go to http://[local-ip-of-server-computer] to see if it worked. It did.
7. Now, I configured the httpd.conf to "Request all granted"
8. Next, I went on ahead to port forward. My router is Frontier Netgear router.
9. I went to 192.168.254.254 (Frontier's router addresss) > Firewall Settings > Port Forwarding > Add
10. I selected "World Wide Web (HTTP)" and "OK".
11. Then I went to the menu and to "DMZ Host". I enabled my server computer for that.
12. With my main PC, I went on ahead to my public WAN IP mentioned on the router page. It didn't work.

Whenever I try to load my http://[router-public-wan-ip], Google Chrome gets a "Webpage not avaliable. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

I have port forwarded on my server PC's Windows Firewall.
My httpd.conf is set to be on port 80. Also, I have changed my ServerName to [local-server-computer-ip]:80.

Can anyone provide any advice? Thanks.

Comment: first go to http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm and  search for your router settings then check the open port for 80 through this site http://www.canyouseeme.org/

Comment: Port is open. I checked it.

Comment: ok try to go to `httpd.conf` then change  ServerName localhost:80` to ServerName <your private IP>:80 for example ServerName <192.168.254.2>:80 then go to Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1 to this Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all then restart your wamp server then you should be able to access your files via public ip .

Comment: @authprivate Did that, then when I checked with my phone on a different data network it worked. Turns out you cant access your own server with public IP, need to use the local private ip. Thnx for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was my mistake. The solution to this problem is that, well, there was no problem at all. I simply hadn't realized that external IP addresses cannot be accessed by their own servers - one inside of the server LAN has to use the server computer's local private IP address.

I sincerely apologize. Thank you to all who contributed.