# How can I access my local development server over the internet?

Tags: wampserver, portforwarding, windows-firewall

I have Wamp 3.1.7 running on a Windows 10 machine. The goal is to have the projects on this server accessible via the internet. 
The server is available and working as expected over LAN when accessed with the LAN IP, e.g. 
`http://10.0.0.3/`.
The server runs behind my router, which has its web interface running on port 80, so when I access my public IP, traffic on port 80 goes to the router login page.

Steps taken to try and solve the issue:

1. change the port my server is listening to from 80 to 8080. (this is working, both locally and over LAN, accessed with http://10.0.0.3:8080)
2. Add inbound rules on windows firewall for port 8080, set to allow all.
3. Add port forwarding on the router settings (forward incoming traffic on port 8080 to local IP 10.0.0.3:8080 as per https://portforward.com/d-link/dsl-g2562dg/)
4. Using PFPortChecker, it says that port 8080 on *public_ip* is open and able to send data.

I remain unable to access my server. When I go to *public_ip*:8080, I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.
As stated above, going to *public_ip* just displays the router login page.
So as far as I can tell: port 8080 is open, my server is accessible over LAN on port 8080.

What am I missing? Where else could my traffic be blocked?

Answer (score 1):

Stupid mistake on my side. 
Answer found here: [Public IP Web Page "Connection Timed Out" When Connected To](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621974/public-ip-web-page-connection-timed-out-when-connected-to)

The issue was that you cannot access the server with the *public_ip* if connected the LAN the server is running on.